# Working with ranges - ruby

Tags: ruby, range

I have a line with the following start and stop points (0,3), meaning it also passes through points 1,2.  I have another line with start and stop points (2,4) which passes through point 3.  Using Ruby, I am trying to find a set of points which are in the first line and not in the second.  In this example, (0, 2) is the desired output.

I've tried creating a range `(0..3)` then converting it to array `(0..3).to_a`.  I've also done the same with the second line co-ordinates i.e. `(2..4).to_a`.

I was trying to get what is contained in one array that is not in the other.  When I subtract arrays i.e. `(0..3).to_a - (2..4).to_a` I get [0,1]. I want to get [0,2].  Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: `(0..3).to_a - (2..4).to_a` -> `[0,1,2,3] - [2,3,4]` - what should the result be?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question a bit? `I was trying to get what is contained in one array that is not in the other ..... I want to get a [0,2]`. It's a bit confusing?

Comment: Why would you want to get `2` in the results when you've excluded then in the `2..4` range? If you're talking about sets, you should be using this method. If you're talking about one-dimensional vectors, you should be using a different approach.

Comment: It appears to me that your question is this: given ranges f=(a..b) and g=(c..d), what is the range comprised of values v in f such that v <= c or v >= d? Correct?

Comment: @HarshGupta since they are points, I want to get a line with points that are not contained in the other. In my case a line with points [0,2] is not in the line with points [2,4]. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CarySwoveland that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? (If so, the problem was figuring out the question, not the answer.)

```
def doit(a, b)
  a.to_a.reject {|e| e > b.first && e < b.last}
end

doit (0..3),(2..4)  # => [0,1,2]
doit (0..4),(2..4)  # => [0,1,2,4]
doit (0..3),(0..4)  # => [0]
doit (1..3),(0..4)  # => []
doit (0..3),(-3..1) # => [1,2,3]
doit (1..3),(2..2)  # => [1,2,3]
doit (1..4),(2..3)  # => [1,2,3,4]
```

or

```
def doit(a, b)
  a = a.to_a
  b.size < 3 ? a : a-(b.first+1..b.last-1).to_a  
end
```